# Running two GPUs one for CUDA and one for strictly monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, gpu

Probably a dumb question, so I have a system with a Tesla C2075, however the card only has one DVI port. Is there a way I could simply do the heavy lifting with the tesla card and use another card (old quadro) to run displays?

EDIT: I understand that I can SLI two cards, but that'll limit things to the lesser card AFAIK

Comment: What operating system?  Most modern ones will happily let multiple cards coexist.

Comment: I;m running windows vista 64-bit and ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In my work I use a pc with an Geforce GTX 760 for cuda and a 8400GS. My motherboard dosn't has SLI support and I put the 760 in a pciex 16x slot and the 8400 in a 16x (but 4x eletrically) slot. The only problem in this setup is that my BIOS thinks that the 760 is the primary display card and I have to plug a monitor on the 760 if I need to access BIOS setup. Another person in my office has a Tesla C2075 for cuda and a quadro for display.

Windows has the restriction that both cards have to be from Nvidia. In Linux, you probably can use a card from another vendor to control the display.